# Logging framework for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, logging, log4j, hdfs, apache-commons-logging

I have to work on a logging framework that would capture the logs for a hadoop job that would load data from hdfs, process the data, store the processed data into hdfs and then sqoop the stored data to another file system when needed. I am new to logging framework and not sure about how to start. I am looking for suggestions on how to proceed with the logging framework for the above requirement.

FYI, there will be user defined defined exceptions and messages that would be part of the logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Log4j (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). It comes with Hadoop so no need to add any libraries.

Log4j is pretty simple, to log message you just use
`logger.info("info message")`
to log error message with exception use `logger.error("error message",exceptionObject)`

Here is example code on how to use Log4j in a Mapper class. Same goes for your Driver and Reducer

```
package com.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyMapper.class);

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //logger.error("This is error", e);
        logger.error("This is error");
        logger.warn("This is warning");
        logger.info("This is info");
        logger.debug("This is info");
        logger.trace("This is info");
    }
}
```

If you have hadoop cluster the log message from individual mapper/reducers will be in the nodes that executed them